# Codename one: Why am I getting "/ by zero" when trying to scale an image

Tags: java, image, scale, codenameone

I am trying to scale an image to fit the screen width.

Therefore I am trying to load the imported multi image in the *beforeTerminalGUI* method here:

```
@Override
protected void beforeTerminalGUI(Form f) {
    ImageViewer iv = findImageViewer(f);

    Image i = fetchResourceFile().getImage("stillstand.PNG");
    i.scaledWidth(iv.getWidth());

    iv.setImage(i);
}
```

which was created when I clicked the *beforeShow* event in the gui builder. (I also saved the GUI builder after doing so)

But I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.scaleArray(JavaSEPort.java:3505)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.scale(JavaSEPort.java:3497)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scale(Image.java:961)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledImpl(Image.java:931)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaled(Image.java:896)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledWidth(Image.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.scaledWidth(EncodedImage.java:536)
    at userclasses.StateMachine.beforeTerminalGUI(StateMachine.java:37)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.beforeShow(StateMachineBase.java:537)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2512)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showContainerImpl(UIBuilder.java:2334)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showContainer(UIBuilder.java:2214)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder$FormListener.actionPerformed(UIBuilder.java:2900)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:338)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.actionCommandImpl(Form.java:1415)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.dispatchCommand(Form.java:1381)
    at com.codename1.ui.SideMenuBar$CommandWrapper$ShowWaiter.run(SideMenuBar.java:1611)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1147)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1091)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:994)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

same happens for the methods `i.scale (..)`,`i.scaledHeight(..)` whenever I run the app and want to switch to the TerminalGUI.

I am new to CodenameOne and any help is welcome.

Comment: My guess is that either `iv` or `i` currently have a width or height of 0. Maybe if the GUI is not yet loaded, the ImageViewer is not yet initialized and so has a width/height of 0. Alternatively, maybe `stillstand.PNG` does not exist, and so you have an empty `Image` object. I would drop a breakpoint in the method and check both these things.

Comment: @Oliver Thanks, but tried both of them, they both exist - and I followed an official tutorial in doing this (maybe its outdated? dunno..)

Comment: Have you checked the width/height of them both as well as their existence?

Comment: Well, setting a breakpoint comes to the conclusion, that the error occurrs **before** the method is called - wtf?

Comment: I mean, the app is not running into the breakpoint at all, it simply skips it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is  `iv.getWidth()` You should use `iv.getImage().getWidth()`, this will return the width of the ImageViewer's image and not the width of the component itself. Also check for existence of the image `stillstand.PNG` before scaling it.

```
@Override
protected void beforeTerminalGUI(Form f) {
    ImageViewer iv = findImageViewer(f);
    Image i = Resources.openLayered("/theme").getImage("stillstand.PNG");
    if (i != null) {
        i.scaledWidth(iv.getImage().getWidth());
        iv.setImage(i);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Image not found");
    }
}
```

Another way to scale the image to fit the screen width is doing this:

```
@Override
protected void beforeTerminalGUI(Form f) {
    ImageViewer iv = findImageViewer(f);
    Image i = Resources.openLayered("/theme").getImage("stillstand.PNG");
    if (i != null) {
        iv.setImage(i.scaledWidth(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Image not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also add that image viewer scales images to fit by default so scaling the image is probably a mistake that might cause artifacts in the resulting image